# Gravitational waves' Amplitude

Tags: gravity, waves, gravitational-waves

Gravitational waves are disturbances in gravitational field which in turn is the curvature of space-time. So my question is it possible to somehow measure the amplitude of a gravitational wave and if it is possible what is the baseline against which this amplitude is measured

Comment: What do you think LIGO does?

Comment: The gravitational wave is measured by the difference in time it takes light to reach the same point from two different paths. This "difference" can be measured and you could call large differences as higher amplitudes.  However one could argue that this only measures the amplitude of gravitational waves of a certain frequency and thus may not be completely precise, but it is a rough estimate.